# Truth or not about Islam rules

Tags: sharia

I have a few questions if I may. I have no idea if this is true or not since it's really hard to find this stuff online, nevertheless, here are my questions as a total newbie in Islam.

1. Is it true that Islam prohibits eating "food on top of food"? I mean having two types of different foods in one meal? For example soups and steak?
2. Is it true that if you get wealthy you have to feed the poor in your city one a week on the weekends?
3. And of course, is Quran in general tolerant? I mean is it really strict in it's rules (I have not read it myself, yet, but I will one day).
4. Any other good/impressive guidelines that Quran offers are more then welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the Shari'ah (Islamic Constitution) deeds and actions are divided
>   into five classes:
>
> Fardh or Wajib:   فرض او واجـب  An obligatory duty the omission of
>   which is Islamicly punishable.
>
> Mus'tahab:  مسـتـحب  An action which is rewarded, but whose omission
>   is not punishable.
>
> Mu'baah::     مـباحAn action which is permitted but legally is
>   indifferent.
>
> Mak'rooh: مكـروه   An action which is disapproved by the Shari'ah but
>   is not under any penalty.
>
> Haram:  An action which is forbidden, and Islamicly punishable.
>   ([Reference](http://www.islamic-laws.com/hadithoverview.htm))

**1- Is it true that islam prohibits eating "food on top of food"? I mean having two types of different foods in one meal? For example soups and steak?**

no. but it is recommended in Islam. there are many recommendations regarding health specially by Imam Sadiq a.s. and Imam Riza a.s. but I do not know any English references for them.

**2- Is it true that if you get wealthy you have to feed the poor in your city one a week on the weekends?**

no but you should pay Khums and Zikat (whenever was applied to you)

**3- And of course, is Quran in general tolerant? I mean is it really strict in it's rules(I have not read it myself, yet, but I will one day).**

there are four type of rules as I said. but in general Islam is easy religion for going paradise. but for meeting God it is more difficult. in fact it depends on you what you are seeking. only escaping hell? entering paradise? what floor of paradise? paradise has floors same as number of verses of Quran. or you want to meet God? higher level needs higher work and pain. no pain no gain.

**Any other good/impressive guidelines that Quran offers are more then welcome.**

Quran is full of guidelines. [here](http://www.al-islam.org/) is full of good/impressive guidelines that Quran offers.

Comment: a good answer too. Me, being non-islamic, discovered so much more new and good from this website and you guys. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

## Is it true that islam prohibits eating "food on top of food"? I mean having two types of different foods in one meal? For example soups and steak?

I don't believe there is any Ayah or Hadith that says it is not permissible to eat food over food.

## Is it true that if you get wealthy you have to feed the poor in your city one a week on the weekends?

I have never come across an Ayah or Hadith that states it has to be on weekends but there are Ayahs and Hadiths that state it is a Must to give to the poor, this is ether zakat or sadaqah.

> Righteousness is not that you turn your faces toward the east or the
>   west, but [true] righteousness is [in] one who believes in Allah , the
>   Last Day, the angels, the Book, and the prophets and gives wealth, in
>   spite of love for it, to relatives, orphans, the needy, the traveler,
>   those who ask [for help], and for freeing slaves; [and who]
>   establishes prayer and gives zakah; [those who] fulfill their promise
>   when they promise; and [those who] are patient in poverty and hardship
>   and during battle. Those are the ones who have been true, and it is
>   those who are the righteous.

[Surat Al Baqarah Ayah 177](http://quran.com/2/177)

> It was narrated from Salman bin 'Amir that the Prophet said: "Giving
>   charity to a poor person is charity, and (fiving) to a relative is two
>   things, charity and upholding the ties of kinship." (Sahih)
>
> أَخْبَرَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ الأَعْلَى، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا خَالِدٌ،
>   قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ عَوْنٍ، عَنْ حَفْصَةَ، عَنْ أُمِّ الرَّائِحِ،
>   عَنْ سَلْمَانَ بْنِ عَامِرٍ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ
>   ‏ "‏ إِنَّ الصَّدَقَةَ عَلَى الْمِسْكِينِ صَدَقَةٌ وَعَلَى ذِي
>   الرَّحِمِ اثْنَتَانِ صَدَقَةٌ وَصِلَةٌ ‏"‏ ‏.‏

[Sunan Annasa'i](http://sunnah.com/urn/1077590)

so you can give charity at any time, not just on weekends.  And actually zakat is different from sadaqah, zakat is obligatory Sadaqah is voluntary, and actually sadaqah is translated as voluntary charity.  Zakat has seperate rules telling how much should be given, when and to whom it should be given and so on.

## And of course, is Quran in general tolerant? I mean is it really strict in it's rules(I have not read it myself, yet, but I will one day).

You are asking for a perspective, and that really differs from person to person.  If you ask a strong Muslim, they would most likely say it is just, but the answer will differ in the level the Muslim is in.

### I do not understand your last question.